# HTML email template builder using Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, drag-and-drop, editor

I want to build an interactive html page builder using drag n drop.

Basically it will have elements like image, section, text etc which a user can use to build a HTML page.

Any suggestions for third party Delphi components which I can use for HTML editor?

Comment: Delphi uses Object Pascal language, not HTML. If you're looking for an embedded browser, I would suggest Chromium based one, like e.g. [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi). The rest is about searching HTML project that can do what you want and getting HTML source from that browser. Oh, and it is off-topic to ask for component suggestions on Stack Overflow. Maybe on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site, but you must have very specific criteria.

Comment: Hint: instead of using HTML directly, you may compose the template using a much simpler markup language (for example markdown), and generate/refresh the HTML from this markup in a second step. This decouples content and visual representation. You could still have a "live" HTML preview.

Comment: @Victoria Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mjn42 thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What @Victoria says.  If you are looking for something which is purely a page builder (with no facility for the user to edit the page contents) take a look at TPageProducer on the Internet tab of the Component Pallete.  It includes a surprisingly flexible parameter-substitution mechanism which you could use as a kind of macro-expansion facility to build a page from boilerplate pieces.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find software libraries, tools, books, tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here, which is very clearly explained in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Why has this question not been closed yet? It's very clearly off-topic here. Out of 3 experienced users prior to myself, only one of them actually voted to close?

Comment: @JerryDodge:  I haven't vtc'ed yet because i don't think the q is clear enough in what the OP actually wants.  If it is just a request for a suggestion for a 3rd party editor, then it is off-topic, but I'm not so sure  that's what the OP really wants.  That's why I mentioned TPageProducer, because that can do exactly what the OP says he wants to do in his first 2 paras.  And if that's *all* he wants, no 3rd party "editor" is required.

Comment: @MartynA I'm absolutely sure the `TPageProducer` doesn't support drag and drop. It's not even a visual control. It's an event driven non-visual component. FWIW, our company just paid $1,200 for a component library for this exact same purpose.

Comment: Not per se, but with a little ingenuity it could be woven into a drag 'n drop gui.  Imagine the the bits to be built from are displayed somehow ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [HTML Component Library](https://www.delphihtmlcomponents.com/). It includes an editor. Check this blog post for an introduction [HTMLComponents, the native Delphi html rendering engine](https://jonlennartaasenden.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/htmlcomponents-the-native-delphi-html-rendering-engine/)